# Is there a way to create package.config for development only in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a list of nuget packages that I only use for development. I know in node you have devDependencies. Is there a similar way in visual studio? What's important for me is to control which packages gets carried over to production.

Answer (score 0):

My team mate figured out the solution to this which is using **conditional assembly reference**. So the package will still be restored when the package is build but it won't be included in the deployment of the final build.

https://heejune.me/2016/02/17/c-conditional-assembly-reference/